# remove element based on values found in another element xslt-3

Tags: xslt-3.0

The following works:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
     <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>
    
     <xsl:template match=
     "*[ID='579']/EMAIL"/>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

But i need to remove the email element based on many ID values
something like below is not working:

```
"*[ID='579|987|1023']/EMAIL"/>
```

How would you do it i a more cleverway with xslt-3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a string sequence parameter e.g.

```
<xsl:param name="ids" as="xs:string*" select="'579', '987', '1023'"/>
```

then you can use `match="*[ID = $ids]/EMAIL"`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:param name="ids" as="xs:string*" select="'579', '987', '1023'"/>

  <xsl:template match="*[ID = $ids]/EMAIL"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or pass in a single string separated with `|` and use `match="*[ID = tokenize($ids, '\|')]/EMAIL"`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:param name="ids" as="xs:string" select="'579|987|1023'"/>

  <xsl:template match="*[ID = tokenize($ids, '\|')]/EMAIL"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thankk you, so how the question xslt should become?

Comment: @dalibic, I have spelled it out though I think you should have been able to edit that yourself.

Comment: i want to really thank you for all your answers. I am noob, and i find it easier to learn by seeing in your answers an example from start to end of the script. To be honest, i copy paste many useful snippets from your answers, for creating a library of clever examples. Again thank you for sharing knowledge